# How to offset smooth-scroll to account for height of static navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am currently using Bootstrap for my website.

I am using the navbar from Bootstrap, and each of my HTML section tags has an id (ex: #about-section, #contact-section)

This allows me to use anchor tags like `href="#about-section"` for smooth scrolling to any section.

This works wonderfully, however once I introduced my navbar to be static, whenever I click on a navigation link that is supposed to smooth scroll me to the section, it smooth scrolls but the navbar covers a big portion of the section.

I have seen solutions but that use jQuery. What is the native JS way of doing this?

Comment: What have you found in your research? I'm sure researching `javascript scroll` will give you many answers.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post needs improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you two ways to solve this issue. Way 1 is easy with CSS and way 2 is with javascript.

**Way 1: `padding-top`**

Use `padding-top` to your section. The value of `padding-top` will the amount of height of the navbar. So when the scroll occurs to that section, actually it will start from the top. But for padding-top you can see the section after the navbar.

**Way 2: Javascript**

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link"); // or any other selector what you want

for (const link of links) {
  link.addEventListener("click", scrollToSection);
}

function scrollToSection(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const href = this.getAttribute("href");
  const offsetTop = document.querySelector(href).offsetTop;
  const navbarHeight = document.querySelector(".navbar").offsetHeight

  scroll({
    top: offsetTop - navbarHeight,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}
```